# How to update test case results at bulk in Testlink

Tags: testlink

I've recently started using testlink test management tool in my project and I'm facing a new problem on bulk updation of test cases in testlink.

This is not a problem for manual test cases but for automation it is tedious to update the result (Pass or Fail) of every single test case that you executed.
I have around 5000+ test cases and 50% of them are automated so when the automated.

So, when the automation script is finished executing 2500+ test cases for a particular release, I need to update the result of all these  test cases manuall in testlink as Pass or Fail.

I also tried to link the automation tool with testlink but that didn't worked out.

So, I just want to know if there's any easy way to bulk update the test cases in testlink. May be using some DB queries and all?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's difficult because you should know several data in order to insert the correct information for your project, test plan, build, testsuite, testcase and testcase version. So, you will need all this information.

Anyway, the table to insert the information is ***"executions"*** with the following query you can check the needed information:

```
select * from executions;
```

Regards, David.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can use the XML-RPC API
2) generate a XML file with Format for importing results, then upload it manually

avoid using direct access to DB via SQL

Answer (score 0):

iam also updating the test link using Selenium webdriver

the code is below :-

public class appFunctions extends Keywords {
     // Substitute your Dev Key Here

```
public static String DEV_KEY= "1eab09b6158d9df31e76142b85253243";

   public static String SERVER_URL  = "https://testlink.fondsdepotbank.de/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php";


public static void clearXLResults() throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        int testStepsRow=DriverScript.xlObj.getRowCount("TestSteps");
        int controllerRow=DriverScript.xlObj.getRowCount("Controller");

        //Clear previous results
        for(int i=2;i<=testStepsRow;i++)
        {
            DriverScript.xlObj.setCellData("TestSteps",DriverScript.testStepsStatusCol, i, "");
        }
        for(int j=2;j<=controllerRow;j++)
        {
            DriverScript.xlObj.setCellData("Controller", DriverScript.controllerStatusCol, j, "");
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.writeLog("Unable to clear previous test results in excel");

    }
}


public static void updateResultsTestLink() throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        TestLinkAPIClient api=new TestLinkAPIClient(DEV_KEY, SERVER_URL);
        String result;
        //read controller status
        int controllerRow=DriverScript.xlObj.getRowCount("Controller");
        for(int k=2;k<=controllerRow;k++)
        {
            String currentRowStatus=DriverScript.xlObj.getCellData("Controller",DriverScript.controllerStatusCol,k);
            String currentRowProject=DriverScript.xlObj.getCellData("Controller",DriverScript.controllerProjectCol,k);
            String currentRowPlan=DriverScript.xlObj.getCellData("Controller",DriverScript.controllerPlanCol,k);
            String currentRowBuild=DriverScript.xlObj.getCellData("Controller",DriverScript.controllerBuildCol,k);
            String currentRowTCID=DriverScript.xlObj.getCellData("Controller",DriverScript.controllerTCIDCol,k);
            if(currentRowStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("pass"))
            {
                result= TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED;
                api.reportTestCaseResult(currentRowProject, currentRowPlan, currentRowTCID, currentRowBuild, null, result);
            }
            if(currentRowStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("fail"))
            {
                result= TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED;
                api.reportTestCaseResult(currentRowProject, currentRowPlan, currentRowTCID, currentRowBuild, null, result);
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.writeLog("Unable to update results in Testlink");
    }

}
```